# Calculating PI using Monte Carlo method gives imprecise answer

Tags: c, pi

I am trying to calculate PI using Monte Carlo method. My code gives the result 3.000 no matter how big MAXLEN is. After debugging it many times, I couldn't get what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define sqr2(x) ((x)*(x))
#define frand() ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX))
#define MAXLEN 1000


int circumscribed(int radius){
    float xcoord = frand();
    float ycoord = frand(); 
    float coord = sqr2(xcoord) + sqr2(ycoord);

    if(coord <= radius)
        return 1;
    return -1;      
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int circles = 0, rect = 0;;
    for(i = 0; i < MAXLEN; i++)
    {
        if(circumscribed(1) > 0)   // if(circumscribed(1)) shoul be enough but it doesn't work. Very odd in my opinion.
            circles++;
        rect++;  //this is equal to MAXLEN, I just used it for debugging
    }

    float PI = 4 * circles / rect;
    printf("PI is %2.4f: \n", PI);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: I'm not using C for years but try `float PI = 4.0 * circles / rect;`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [divide floats with integers in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331054/divide-floats-with-integers-in-c)

Comment: Can you say ["Integer Truncation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error) ;)?

Comment: You might also want to consider seeding the random number generator before you use it.

Comment: Tthat solved it, thanks all. I'll accept the answer by @Bill after 7 minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `circles` and `rect` are both `int`, the result of `4 * circles / rect` will be an `int`.  Use floating point numbers instead.

```
float PI = 4.0 * (float)circles / rect;
```

Answer (score 2):

This expression is all integers:

```
4 * circles / rect;
```

Therefore, the result is an integer (3 in this case).

(as a similar example:  `10 / 3 == 3`, but `10.0 / 3.0 == 3.333333`)

Try instead:

```
4.0 * circles / rect;
```

Just changing the `(int)4` to a `(double)4` by referring to it as `4.0` or even `4.` should be enough.

---

**Other Misc Observations**

This line has an extra semi-colon:

```
int circles = 0, rect = 0;;
```

Your function `circumscribed` uses `float`.  Your variable `PI` is also a `float`. 
If you use `double`, you'll get greater precision.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing `integer Math` here. `circles` and `rect` are both `int` in your code, so the result of `4 * circles / rect` is also an `int`. Use floating point numbers instead. Use `double` for better precision.

```
double PI = 4.0 * (double)circles / rect;
```

Comment: FYI, I've rolled back some of your previous edits as per these discussions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/217057 http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165700/217057 http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112275/217057

Comment: +1 for using `double` as 4.0 is a double and the printf() promotes the PI argument, if left as a float, to a double anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing integer math here:

```
float PI = 4 * circles / rect;
```

Changing `4` to `4.0` is sufficient to fix the problem:

```
float PI = 4.0 * circles / rect;
```

Working version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0f69929a42d4a9c0ee13c6bf263a77b4-e72f18108d9179766e8329ba26c9a7c1)

Answer (score 1):

```
float PI = 4 * circles / rect;
```

This performs integer math to the right of the `=` thus limiting your result to 1 significant digit.

Instead:

```
double PI = 4.0 * circles / rect;  // Best
```

---

Details

```
float PI = 4.0 * (float)circles / rect;  // OK
```

Recommend avoid using `float`.  Use `double` instead to avoid limiting this Monte Carlo to about 7 digits.  As `circles` becomes large, it may not convert exactly into the same `float` value.  Instead it converts into a rounded `float`.  This happens at about `circles` > 8,000,000 on many machines.  By rounding, you are unnecessarily limiting the attainable precision.  Using a `double`, this rounding does not occur until `circles` is about 9e15.

```
float PI = 4.0 * (double) circles / rect; // Better
```

The explicit cast of `(double) circles` may be useful to the reader, but code will perform the same way with or without it.  4.0 is a `double` and will cause a `double` promotion to `circles` before the multiplicity occurs, even without the cast.

```
double PI = 4.0 * circles / rect; // Better
```

As the `4.0 * ...` result is a double, best precision is retained by saving to a double.  Using `float PI` causes the multiplication/division, which was done in double precision to reduce its precision on saving to a float.

```
float or double PI = ...
printf("PI is %2.4f: \n", PI);
```

Note: Here, a `PI` converted to a double is passed to `printf()` regardless if PI was declared `float` or `double`.  So might as access the precision in PI by declaring it double.

---

Note: int, float and double range and precision are machine dependent.  The above reflects a common implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**CHECK OUT THIS CODE:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SEED 35791246

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int niter=0;
   double x,y;
   int i,count=0; /* # of points in the 1st quadrant of unit circle */
   double z;
   double pi;

   printf("Enter the number of iterations used to estimate pi: ");
   scanf("%d",&niter);

   /* initialize random numbers */
   srand(SEED);
   count=0;
   for ( i=0; i<niter; i++) {
      x = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
      y = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
      z = x*x+y*y;
      if (z<=1) count++;
      }
   pi=(double)count/niter*4;
   printf("# of trials= %d , estimate of pi is %g \n",niter,pi);

return 0;
}
```